How can i actually play my pygame game using github. On a chromebook where i can't download chrome extensions (school laptop)
I am trying to get started with pygame to make a game in github, i have the right version and i have installed pygame using "pip install pygame" in the terminal (i got the message that it got downloaded). I rewrote a simple code from a tutorial which should work, but i run it and nothing happens. I honestly don't even know what's supposed to happen but i want to have a screen for my game.
I tried running the code and i expected maybe a picture in picture tab to show up but idk.

Hey welcome  to SO, yout question in its state is unlikely to receive an answer. You should try to give a minimal and reproducible example.

Remember that we can't see you try things: you're going to have to explain how you installed python, what code you're using, which exact steps you're using to run your script, and what "nothing happens" means, because something always happens, even if that's "no output is written to the terminal but I also don't get a new prompt". Give the posting guidelines a read, and then [edit] your post to add in the currently missing details.
